# Finding explicit solution to $-\Delta u + u =f$ using Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

This is a question from a previous year's qualifying exam, so it's possible we haven't covered all the material this year in order to solve this problem (we did not discuss PDEs in the class so far, and I don't believe we are going to, so perhaps this question on a previous qual will be beyond the scope of this year's qual):

> The problem concerns finding an explicit solution to the equation $-\Delta u + u =f$ for $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ using the Fourier transform and its inverse.
>
> a) Assume the solution $u$ and all its first-order and second-order partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ are in $L^1 \cap L^2$. Prove: $$\hat{u}(z) = \frac{\hat{f}(z)}{1+4\pi^2|z|^2}$$
>
> b) Prove via the identity $(1+4\pi^2|z|^2)^{-1} = \int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+4\pi^2|z|^2)} dt$ that: $$u(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}f(y) dm(y)dt$$

I have no idea how to actually prove part a. For part b, I tried the following:

$$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{u}(z)e^{2\pi i zx} dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\hat{f}(z)}{1+4\pi^2|z|^2}e^{2\pi i zx} dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+4\pi^2|z|^2)} \hat{f}(z)e^{2\pi i zx} dtdz$$

I can switch the order of integration with Fubini's Theorem, and that matches the order of integration in the solution, but I don't see how to proceed from there.

Comment: Use `\Delta` for the Laplacian.

Comment: start with $\hat{u}(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x) e^{-2\pi i zx} dx$ (since we are told that $u \in L^1$ we are not affraid) the same for the Fourier transform of $f$ and $\Delta u$, and apply the differential equation

Comment: You use the convolution theorem. $\hat{f}\hat{g}=C\widehat{f\star g}$ where there is a constant that depends on the normalization of your Fourier transform.